# Assistance Needed To Merge Two MySQL Tables

Tags: mysql, merge

I am a total beginner to MySQL, I purchased a wordpress site on flippa, it has over 1000 posts on it, I exported the database file for the posts, changed domain servers to my host etc, hooked up to a new sql database, however the 1000 odd posts I imported are in a different table name and not showing in my wp-admin site.  I need to merge the two tables (the old database one and the current database one together) - The only thing is I have absolutely no idea how, I have searched help but do not know where exactly in the mysql I need go and what I need to enter there to merge these tables as there is no simple copy and paste function that I can find - can anyone assist a total dummy.
My old table containing the 1000+ posts is called wp_b93p4k_posts and the new database table I need to merge into is wp_shxt4q_posts - I am grateful for your help and patience with a total beginner at mysql (I have tried importing the posts direct into wordpress using an .xml file but it exceeds the limit for wordpress, I even tried halving the .xml document into two and only successfully imported 111 posts into the correct table) - I am out of options other than mysql route!

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to run some SQL directly on your MySQL backend, there may be a way to do this.  (Note:  if you're going to run SQL directly against the backend database, you will need to ensure that there are no related tables that will need to be updated.  It sounds like you know your way around things, so I'll leave you to look into that.)

The basic format of the SQL would be something like:

INSERT INTO new_table (column1, column2, column3, etc.)
SELECT oldColumn1, oldColumn2, oldColumn3 FROM old_table;

This will select all the rows from your old table and INSERT that data into your new table.  You would need to make sure that the columns match correctly as well.  (For instance, oldColumn1 in the old table contains the data that should go in column1 in the new table.)

As an alternative, it sounded like importing the xml document partially worked, so maybe you need to break your file into smaller chunks and import things piece by piece?